# How to do what MATLAB does with array[index:index] in Maxima?

Tags: matlab, maxima

I can't figure out how to dynamically take a portion at a time of a column vector in Maxima; for example I have the vector `v = [a, b, c, d, e]` and I want to take this: `[a]`, `[a, b]`, `[a, b, c]`, etc.
How can you do this in Maxima?

Answer (score 0):

Maxima doesn't have range indexing as in Matlab. A way to get that is to say `makelist(A[i], i, i1, i2)` where `i1` and `i2` is the range you want. This is equivalent to `A(i1:i2)` in Matlab.